# Wrapping text in column headers while avoiding weird hyphenation

Tags: tables, hyphenation, wrap

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}  
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \hline  
        Model & \multicolumn{1}{m{2.5cm}}{Something Before XYZ} & \multicolumn{1}{m{2.5cm}}{Something After XYZ} &  \multicolumn{1}{m{2.5cm}}{Ratio (Before/After)} & \multicolumn{1}{m{2.5cm}}{Difference (Before-After)}\\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{Model 1}  & 0,707464 & 0,665557 & 1,062964 & 0,041906 \\
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

How can I get the text to wrap so that "Something" is on a line by itself, then "Before XYZ" is on a line by itself, and also for the column with Ratio so that "Ratio" is on a line by itself and "(Before/After)" is on a line by itself?

[image]

Comment: Make us of package `ragged2e`.

Comment: you can force line breaks with `\newline` better to use a nested tabular than multicolumn{1}{m} as then you don't need to guess a width

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way uses the `\thead` command, from `makecell`: it allows for line breaks in standard cells.

I added some improvements with the `booktabs` rules, which add some padding around horizontal lines. Also, you shouldn't center  tables with a `center` environment, as `table` adds some vertical spacing, and `center` will add another, redundant, spacing. Use the `\centering` command instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering  
    \begin{tabular}{lcccc}
        \toprule
        Model & \thead{Something\\ Before XYZ} & \thead{Something\\ After XYZ} & \thead{Ratio\\ (Before/After)} & 
        \thead{Difference\\ (Before-After)}\\
        \midrule
        \textbf{Model 1} & 0,707464 & 0,665557 & 1,062964 & 0,041906
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!